# Search multiple values and copy below cell to next sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel sheet (Original) with 30K+ rows, there is a Header row followed by value row, the whole excel sheet rows are alternating like this.

What I need is to copy the list of all unique Headers in one row to new sheet (Desired), and all its related values below the corresponding headers.

In short, I am trying to consolidate "Original" sheet in "Desired".

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

This is my sample Original Sheet:

```
Header1  Header6  Header5  Header3  Header4  Header2
1        223      3        4        5        6
Header4  Header3  Header2  Header6  Header5  Header1  Header7
12       53       879      234      546      123      876
Header2  Header3  Header5  Header6  Header4  Header1
abc      sdf      weroit   scfm     Aasd     ertmn
Header5  Header3  Header8  Header6  Header2  Header1  Header7  Header4
123      sdf      564      sdg      nhd      234      vdsq     234
```

This is my desired sheet:

```
Header1  Header2  Header3  Header4  Header5  Header6  Header7  Header8
1        6        4        5        3        223
123      879      53       12       546      234      876
ertmn    abc      sdf      Aasd     weroit   scfm
234      nhd      sdf      234      123      sdg      vdsq     564
```

Thanks- Rakesh

Comment: You could fairly easily achieve this with (for example) a Python script. Is that an option at all?

Comment: What is consistent about the data, anything?  Is it literally every other row is the header and the row below is always the 1, 223, abc, sdf, etc?  Is that reliably consistent?  Also, is there a max number of columns, i.e. Header8

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for (a) providing a data sample (even space delimited!) and (b) the desired result (even consistent with the data sample!)

Using formulae, one option possibility is as below:

- Work on a copy of your spreadsheet.
- Clone your entire array alongside the existing one (I’d guess into `I1:P30000`).
- Delete (shift up) the first row of the ‘clone’.
- Filter `ColumnI` based on ‘Contains: Header’ and delete entire rows.
- Cut and insert `I` alongside `A` .. to .. `O` (alongside what should be `M`).
- Copy ‘Header1’ into `Q1` and drag to the right until ‘Header8’.
- Insert the formula below in `Q2` and copy across/down as required:

  > =IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$P2,1,MATCH(R$1,$A2:$P2,0)+1),"")
- Select entire sheet contents and Copy > Paste Special > Values.
- Delete `A:Q`, Left align and Save as “Desired”.

This seems quite viable for occasional use, though obviously VBA wins hands down if required often. So maybe turn on macro recorder while taking the above steps?